# How to configure Spanish Speech under MS Windows 7 English

Tags: windows-7, text-to-speech, text-to-speech-voices, speech, spanish

I need to get working Spanish Speech Recognition under clean MS Windows 7 Pro English.

[image]

I found some links  but it is not what I need as I see...

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/set-speech-recognition#1TC=windows-7

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/language-packs#lptabs=win7

http://www.rose-medical.com/sr-upgrade.html

Which are steps to configure it? Thank you!

Comment: What version of Windows 7 do you have?  Realistically, only Windows 7 Ultimate, support language packs.

Comment: Your edition does not support adding multiple language packs (for free), in order to use the speech recognizer in Spanish, you need the Spanish language pack installed. If you have information that clarifies your  question edit the question, to include that information, and delete your comment.

Comment: @Ramhound Any clue why I cannot install Spanish service pack from here? `http://www.froggie.sk/en/7lp32sp1.html` I mean I click the file but nothing happens. Is some way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some old but working great voice's packages

So I just installed [RealSpeak TTS engine  Spanish (21.7 MB)](http://depositfiles.com/files/6214111)

and got Spanish Voice working!

[image]

If you need more voices you can find them [here](http://www.cross-plus-a.com/balabolka.htm).

Answer (score -1):

This site also has that file - the one you provided does not work on free mode.
http://biblprog.com/en/speech_api/voices_sapi/